# JQueryMobile in conjunction with iOS - tap events double bounce

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

This concerns JQueryMobile javascript running on iOS
Why would the tap event binding cause two events to propagate to the handler about 300ms apart.

```
 $('#container').bind("tap",Handler.tap);
```

Whilst the click event binding only creates the one event

```
 $('#container').bind("click",Handler.tap);
```

Comment: What version of iOS and jQuery Mobile are you using?

Comment: iOS 5.1.1 and JQuery Mobile 1.1.1 
It's a little inconsistent the problem is the single tap works as expected at the top of the screen but I get the double bounce key tap at the bottom. I suspected scrolling down may have something to do with it but it doesn't always scroll.